# Javascript array and image

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay so I've asked this question before but I didn't get the answer that solved my problem, I'll try to explain it better. So let say I have a array with 3 items and let say it landed on 0 I have a code set up for which it will display in div now I need the image to be displayed right next to the array that is displayed.  So another example would be like I have an array of cars, BMW, civic, and Mercedes and let say I have a random number generator and it chooses 1 which is bmw the word will be displayed in the div and if the civic was picked the civic will has a civic logo next to it and if Mercedes was picked Mercedes will have a logo next to it. Also if possible I want the id added in I'll put the CSS of background-image to what ever the pic is(reasoning is I want to add some design in the picture)

Comment: why dont you add the logo of respective brand in respective array keys

Comment: can you explain further what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So what code have you come up with to solve this? You may want to edit your question and include it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

  <ul id="carList">


  </ul>

  <button id="getRandomCar">Get Random Car</button>


</body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready( function(){
    var carsArray = [{
     brand : 'BMW',
     logo : 'link-to-logo.png',
     model : 'BMW X7',
    },
    {
     brand : 'Honda',
     logo : 'link-to-logo.png',
     model : 'Civic',
    },
    {
     brand : 'Mercedez-Benz',
     logo : 'link-to-logo.png',
     model : 'C-Class Sedan',
    }];

function randomNumberGenerator(params) {
  return Math.round(Math.random()*params); 
}

function randomCar() {
  $('#getRandomCar').click( function() {

    var selectedCar = randomNumberGenerator(carsArray.length - 1);
    console.log(selectedCar);
    var template = '<li>';
    template += 'Brand: ' + carsArray[selectedCar].brand + '</br>';
    template += 'Logo: ' + carsArray[selectedCar].logo + '</br>';
    template += 'Model: ' + carsArray[selectedCar].model + '</br>';

    $('#carList').html(template);

  } );
}
        randomCar();
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Try [this](https://jsbin.com/nadaxic/edit?html,js,console,output) as a reference.

I've created an array of objects (carsArray). Since it's an object, you can add properties that you think necessary.

The sample generates a random number, then use it as index for the carsArray. The acquired object values will be injected into a DOM.

Comment: Am I able to get the picture locally

Comment: What do you mean?